# Menu desplegable condicional

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, vb.net

### PREGUNTA

Buenas,

La cuestión es que tengo un menú superior, pero quiero que el ultimo apartado sea condicional, y solo aparezca cuando no esta logeado. Hasta ahora ningún problema.

El quebradero de cabeza me surge ahora, y es que cuando estoy logeado quiero sustituir ese li por un div que hasta ahora tenia colocado en la parte superior de la pagina. Pero obviamente no puedo colocar un div dentro de un listado...

Como puedo meterlo siguiendo la estructura actual?

Este es el menu superior.

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <nav class="nav-main">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="aQuienesSomos" runat="server" href="#">Quienes Somos</a></li>
            <li><a id="aServicios" runat="server" href="#">Servicios</a></li>
            <li><a id="aListadoOfertas" runat="server" href="../sec_publico/OfertasListado.aspx">Ofertas de empleo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
            <li class="login"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i> <a id="aLogin" runat="server" href="#">Zona Privada</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Este es el div del usuario que tengo hasta ahora:

```
<div class="menu-user">
    <label for="ac-2" class="label-user"> <i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="LblNombreInicio2" runat="server"><%=devolvernombre%></asp:Label> <i class="fa fa-caret-down "></i></label>
    <input id="ac-2" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />         
    <div class="menu-dropdown">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a ID="aMisOfertas" class="pure-button" runat="server" value="">
                    <i class="fa fa-briefcase "></i> Mis ofertas
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a ID="aPerfil" class="pure-button" runat="server" value="">
                    <i class="fa fa-id-card"></i> Mi Perfil
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a ID="aSeguridad" class="pure-button" runat="server" value="">
                    <i class="fa fa-lock "></i> Cambiar contraseña
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="abandonar" class="pure-button perfilbtn" runat="server" OnClick="abandonar_Click" value="">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Desconectar
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y en este else es donde me gustaria colocar el div en lugar del li actual:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <nav class="nav-main">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="aQuienesSomos" runat="server" href="#">Quienes Somos</a></li>
            <li><a id="aServicios" runat="server" href="#">Servicios</a></li>
            <li><a id="aListadoOfertas" runat="server" href="../sec_publico/OfertasListado.aspx">Ofertas de empleo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
            <% If Yo Is Nothing Then%>
            <li class="login"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i> <a id="aLogin" runat="server" href="#">Zona Privada</a></li>
            <% Else%>
            <%End If%>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### CORRECCION (codigo algo guarro)

He colocado el div directamente en el li, funciona pero me parece una guarreria de código... Si alguien tiene una solucion mejor que me diga porfa.

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <nav class="nav-main">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="aQuienesSomos" runat="server" href="#">Quienes Somos</a></li>
            <li><a id="aServicios" runat="server" href="#">Servicios</a></li>
            <li><a id="aListadoOfertas" runat="server" href="../sec_publico/OfertasListado.aspx">Ofertas de empleo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
            <% If Yo Is Nothing Then%>
                <li class="login"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i> <a id="aLogin" runat="server" href="#">Zona Privada</a></li>
            <% Else%>
                <li class="login">                    
                    <div class="menu-user">
                        <label for="ac-2" class="label-user"> <i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="LblNombreInicio2" runat="server"><%=devolvernombre%></asp:Label> <i class="fa fa-caret-down "></i></label>
                        <input id="ac-2" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />         
                        <div class="menu-dropdown">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a ID="aMisOfertas" class="pure-button" runat="server" value="">
                                        <i class="fa fa-briefcase "></i> Mis ofertas
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a ID="aPerfil" class="pure-button" runat="server" value="">
                                        <i class="fa fa-id-card"></i> Mi Perfil
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a ID="aSeguridad" class="pure-button" runat="server" value="">
                                        <i class="fa fa-lock "></i> Cambiar contraseña
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="abandonar" class="pure-button perfilbtn" runat="server" OnClick="abandonar_Click" value="">
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Desconectar
                                    </asp:LinkButton>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <%End If%>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```